# HttpClient fails at execute method

Tags: android, http, httpclient, httprequest, httpresponse

It must be some idiotic thing that I am doing but I could not get it what is the problem...

My code snippet

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://somehost/WS2/Upload.aspx?one=valueGoesHere");
    client.execute(request);//it fails at this line
} catch (Exception e) {
```

and in my manifest I have internet access permission

from console

```
W/System.err( 4210): java.net.UnknownHostException: somehost
W/System.err( 4210):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
W/System.err( 4210):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
W/System.err( 4210):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err( 4210):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err( 4210):    at com.temp.services.httpclient.HttpGetDemo.onCreate(HttpGetDemo.java:29)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
W/System.err( 4210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
W/System.err( 4210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 4210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/System.err( 4210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/System.err( 4210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/System.err( 4210):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/ActivityManager(  120): Displayed activity com.temp.services/.httpclient.HttpGetDemo: 119 ms (total 304 ms)
```

Comment: Does the URL actually exist (`http://somehost/WS2/Upload.aspx?one=valueGoesHere`)? Try with `http://www.google.com`, for instance, see if that works.

Comment: Is that the actual URL? If the URL is valid and you are still facing this problem, you should read about DNS-prefetching

Comment: well maybe it is , but I can't get it, and it doesn't work with http://www.google.com neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, What about trying this :

```
URL uri = new URL(rootUri);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following before your http request code

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, can you please explain it?

Comment: It worked for me too . can someone explain why this ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to declare the **INTERNET permission** in the **Android manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your are not running on your main thread, check if you get this exception:
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

Do you execute this request in the emulator or on an android device ?
if it's on the emulator, maybe the internet connection is not shared with it.

If it's on an android device, seems you don't have internet access ( not the permission, just the access )

Comment: well I am connected to Wifi and I have an internet connection, but only my app doesn't works :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the URL is a valid one, I suggest that you should call :

```
try {
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is [DNS pre-fetching](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/dns-prefetching-or-pre-resolving.html) so that your device can resolve it URl to an IP address.

Although this isn't enough for it to guarantee to work. What actually worked for me is a retrying mechanism. Give it some good old F5 F5 F5 F5 till the website responds :D

Comment: tnx, for the snippet but I do not get how can this help with my problem ? cause I have exception at this line client.execute(request) I do not know why ...

Comment: The snippet won't actually help much, what you have to do is implement a retry mechanism. Ignore the exception Run your code in a while loop till you get HTTP a 200  response.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with URL.As it shows in Log Exception is

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: somehost
```

Try with your true URL.

& BTW www.google.com works fine

Comment: I doesn't in my case and I do not know why...W/System.err( 4545): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
W/System.err( 4545):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:512)
W/System.err( 4545):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:300)
W/System.err( 4545):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:259)